# Different versions of the ANOVA decomposition parameters

Tags: anova

I'm trying to study some statistics online and I have difficulties figuring out why I keep encountering slightly different formulas for the parameters of the ANOVA decomposition :
$$
SCT = SCE + SCR
$$

The most common versions of the SCT, SCE, and SCR I met in my courses are the following ones :

$$
SCT = \sum_{i=1}^{n}(y_i-\bar{y})^2 \\
SCE = \sum_{i=1}^{n}(\hat{y_i}-\bar{y})^2 \\
SCR = \sum_{i=1}^{n}(y_i-\hat{y_i})^2
$$

But in some other courses, I met these versions:

$$
SCT = \sum_{i=1}^{k}\sum_{j=1}^{n_i}(y_{ij}-\bar{y})^2 \\
SCE = \sum_{i=1}^{k} n_i (\bar{y_i}-\bar{y})^2 \\
SCR = \sum_{i=1}^{k}\sum_{j=1}^{n_i}(y_{ij}-\bar{y_i})^2
$$

To me, it seems to be the same formulas, and that bothers me because I'm pretty sure I'm missing something...

So, can you tell me if there is a difference, and if this is the case, when I'm supposed to use each version? Thank you!

---

P.S.: I made some tests with a small dataset filled with one qualitative and one quantitative, but I found the same results with both SCT formulas... I don't really understand why the number of classes k in the quantitative variable seems to be important.

Comment: You quote formulas for two different applications: one-way and two-way ANOVA.  At a deeper level they *are* the same formulas, because they express the decomposition of a quadratic form into orthogonal components.  It is clear in any case which one (if either) is applicable: look at the numbers of subscripts you need!

Comment: Thank you, that helps a lot!

Comment: Why does the first formula have **SCT** on both sides?

Comment: It was a typo. Sorry for that.